# Error while passing array as function parameter in bash

Tags: bash

This is the code I am dealing with:

```
function execute {
    task="$1"
    servername="$2"
    "$task" "${servername[@]}" 

}


function someOtherThing {

    val=$1
    echo "$val"

}


function makeNecessaryDirectory {

    arr=("$@")
    echo "${arr[@]}"

}


dem=(1 2 3 4 5)


execute someOtherThing 1
execute makeNecessaryDirectory "${dem[@]}"
```

Output:

```
1
1
```

Expected output:

```
1
1 2 3 4 5
```

How to achieve this? I found no error logically.

`Side question`:

Is it safe to always receive 2nd parameter as an array inside `execute` so that it can deal with both of the dependent functions, or i should have an explicit check inside `execute`?

Comment: You are passing the array as individual args to execute and then only passing the first one the `makeNecessaryDirectory`, so `$@` is just 1.

Comment: Wouldn't your expected output be `1`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5` (all on separate lines)?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, the code portion is edited on `makenecessaryDirectory`.

Comment: Ok. Then why don't you just use `execute() { "$@"; }`? it seems that's what you're after…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in my comment

You are passing the array as individual args to `execute` and then only passing the first one the `makeNecessaryDirectory`, so `$@` is just the single argument passed which is 1.

I would do it this way, I have added comments to the parts i have changed. 
It is only minor changes but should hopefully work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash

function execute {
    task="$1"
    servername="$2"
    "$task" "$servername"
    #No longer pass array here just pass servername as the name of array

}


function someOtherThing {

    val=$1
    echo "$val"

}


function makeNecessaryDirectory {

    local arr=("${!1}") 
    #Indirect reference to the first arg passed to function which is now the
    #name of the array

    for i in "${arr[@]}";
       do
           echo "$i"
       done

}


dem=(1 2 3 4 5)


execute someOtherThing 1
execute makeNecessaryDirectory 'dem[@]' #Pass the array name instead of it's contents
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, i will use it. But how can I achieve the expected output with passing the array elements?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque You can't really, you can't pass array elements, whilst still maintaining the array. Any embedded spaces would be lost. This is the only way i know of to preserve the array as it is between functions. You could use `shift` in  `execute`, and then set `servername` to `$@`, but that is not a very good way to do it.